# Webview - html tag draggable after xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

Have encountered a frustrating/perplexing issue: after updating to a newer version of Xcode, every webview app it generates has either the top-level html tag or the webview itself as draggable, which should not be the case. (Screenshot below) I have been able to replicate the issue in the following scenarios:

- Old app backups, so no code changes on my end seem to be the cause.
- Old and new versions of Xcode
- Different phones with different OS versions
- Different simulators
- Older and new versions of osx (I just updated my computer to a new version of osx that had been putting off)

If I run the copy-pasted project to a different computer with xcode, the app works perfectly fine/this issue doesn't occur. So I've also tried fully removing xcode from the system in case some sort of file or setting got screwed up, which has also not been successful. I've tried clearing the following items:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/Xcode
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
```

Have tried `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`, but haven't been able to get that to work. Also tried to clean out `/private/var/folders/*`, but wasn't successful there either.

It's worth noting that the process I went through to update Xcode was to 1) delete DerivedData, and 2) delete the old xcode app, both to make enough space to get the newer version of xcode. I've done both before in the past and it hasn't caused issues, but maybe something went wrong here?

I honestly am at a total loss; clearly something is screwed up on my system, but do not know what could be causing it. No errors are being generated on the app (in web inspector and xcode console), so there's no help there either. Any advice on even a place to start would be amazing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future users: it appears that switching PhoneGap's config.xml `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />` to `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />` caused the issue to stop occurring. This makes sense given the documentation of:

> DisallowOverscroll (boolean, defaults to false): set to true if you
>   don't want the WebView to rubber-band.

However, what doesn't make sense is what could have changed in Xcode that would have caused Xcode/PhoneGap to start caring about DisallowOverscroll, since it has been set to false for the past 4 years on the app, with 0 issues.